# How to apply search query on related models in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a problem.

I am doing a search function where users will enter the products they want to search via a form and will return the products.

This is the form.

```
<form action="{{ route('shopAll') }}">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search Products...">
    <button type="submit"><i class="ti-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

Product.php

```
    class Product extends Model{
        protected $fillable = [
        'name','added_by', 'user_id', 'category_id', 'subcategory_id', 'subsubcategory_id', 'brand_id', 'video_provider', 'video_link', 'unit_price',
        'purchase_price', 'unit', 'slug', 'colors', 'choice_options', 'variations', 'current_stock'
      ];

    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function subcategory(){
        return $this->belongsTo(SubCategory::class);
    }

    public function subsubcategory(){
        return $this->belongsTo(SubSubCategory::class);
    }

    public function brand(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
    }
}
```

SearchController.php

```
    if($request->search){
        $data['products'] = 
            Product::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%')
            ->orWhere('tags', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%')
            ->orWhere('meta_title', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%')
            ->orWhere('slug', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%')
            ->get();
    } else {
        $data['products'] = Product::paginate(20);
    }
    
    return view('frontend.shop-all', $data);
```

I want to make the query to include "orWhere" on the category, subcategory, subsubcategory and brand so that when users want to search for a product, they can search the brand or any of the attributes related to the product. Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It is very unfortunate structure and will be pita for maintenance/upgrade. You should consider adjacency list or nested list for categories. There is already some packages that utilise this kind of request. Check [laravel-categories by rinvex](https://github.com/rinvex/laravel-categories) for example. It won't you limit to two level children and will give you better abstraction of feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [whereHas/has methdos](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) for querying relationships. Assuming you want to search against the `name` attribute of your relationships (category, subcategory, subsubcategory, brand etc.), at the top of your SearchController.php, add this line:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
```

and then update your query like this:

```
$data['products'] = 
        Product::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%')
        ->orWhere('tags', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%')
        ->orWhere('meta_title', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%')
        ->orWhere('slug', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%')
        ->orWhereHas('category', function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%');
        })
        ->orWhereHas('subcategory', function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%');
        })
        ->orWhereHas('subsubcategory', function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%');
        })
        ->orWhereHas('brand', function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->search . '%');
        })
        ->get();
```

Comment: thank you for the solution. however, I got another problem. "Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::App\Http\Controllers\{closure}() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Builder, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder given". do you have any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: @FirdausNasir I updated the answer. You have to import Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder at the top of your controller, before the class declaration.

Comment: thank you so much for you solution. works like a charm